# Naive way to merge k arrays

Tags: java, arrays, merge

I'm trying to implement an algorithm to merge *k sorted* arrays (each with *n* elements) in a naive way deliberately:

Steps:

1. merge the first and second arrays
2. merge the above resulting array with the 3rd array
3. merge the above resulting array with the 4th array
4. ... and so on until merge with the *k* th array

My code can output the sorted single array for 3x3, 4x4, 5x5 2D arrays, but the it stucks when the 2D array become 6x6.

Is it because the complexity of the code is too bad that it take too long to compile? Or there are some silly logical errors that I am not aware of?

I read through my code and what I guess the problem is the line I marked with "<<<==== ??". How can I make it right?

```java
public class Merge {

    // merge 2 arrays into a single sorted array
    private static int[] merge(int[] arrayA, int[] arrayB) {
        int n1 = arrayA.length;     // number of elements in arrayA
        int n2 = arrayB.length;     // number of elements in arrayB
        int[] mergeArray = new int[n1+n2];

        int i = 0;      // pointer of current index in mergeArray
        int p1 = 0;     // pointer of current index in arrayA
        int p2 = 0;     // pointer of current index in arrayB
        while (p1 < n1 && p2 < n2) {
            // put the lowest number the mergeArray until one of the array is done
            if (arrayA[p1] < arrayB[p2]) {
                mergeArray[i] = arrayA[p1];
                i++;
                p1++;
            }
            else if (arrayB[p2] < arrayA[p1]) {
                mergeArray[i] = arrayB[p2];
                i++;
                p2++;
            }
        }
        // if all elements of arrayA is copied to mergeArray, then copy remaining elements in arrayB to it
        if (p1 >= n1) {
            for (int j = p2; j < arrayB.length; j++) {
                mergeArray[i] = arrayB[j];
                i++;
            }
        }
        // if all elements of arrayB is copied to mergeArray, then copy remaining elements in arrayA to it
        if (p2 >= n2) {
            for (int j = p1; j < arrayA.length; j++) {
                mergeArray[i] = arrayA[j];
                i++;
            }
        }
        return mergeArray;
    }

    public static int[] naiveMerge(int[][] data) {
        int k = data.length;        // number of sorted array
        int n = data[0].length;     // number of elements in each array
        int[] resultArray = new int[k*n];

        int[] tempArray = Merge.merge(data[0], data[1]);   // merge the first two arrays
        for (int i = 2; i < k; i++) {
            // then merge in the third, fourth ... k arrays
            tempArray = Merge.merge(tempArray, data[i]);   // <<<==== ??
            resultArray = tempArray;
        }
        return resultArray;
    }
}
```

The program stuck likes this: Nothing is shown after the last line "After merging:", but the program is still running until I force to terminate it.
[image: program stuck]

Comment: Thanks for commenting your code so well and telling us what you're trying to do. Can you tell us a bit more about what you've tried so far to debug this and why you think that particular line is the problem? Also, what specific errors are you getting? Is the program stuck in a loop? Is it returning the wrong values?

Comment: I have attached a picture of the console output. Basically it doesn't report any error or exception, but  it just stuck like this.

Comment: The reason I point out that particular line is when I use the debugger to step over each line, the program stuck when it steps over this line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the arrays that came up for 3, 4, and 5, you can see that by pure coincidence all the values in all the arrays were unique. However, in your 6 case, notice that there are duplicated values (there's two 46's). Trace through your first `while` loop in `merge`. What happens if the two arrays happen to have the same value in them at some point?

Good luck!

Comment: I got it! Cheers!!